# Make a circle-form from vertices

Tags: vertices

I`ve got closed curve in the center of my mesh. I want to vertices which highlighted by yellow have circle-form, not the form like on the photo. Can i smooth them to circle-form?[image]

Comment: Look at the first method, step (2) and (3).

Comment: Thank you a lot)))

Comment: ... or, after activating the shipped _Loop Tools_ add-on .. its  'Circle' operator

Comment: @Leander  Of course. np at all